# Android "loses" a game

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, apk

I installed [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eamobile.bejeweled2_na_wf) game via APK on my Chinese tablet "Infotmic M799CA", created a desktop shortcut for it and noticed that after a (very frequent) device hang with consequent reboot, the game gets lost.

Tapping on the desktop icon says "Application not installed". I have to reinstall it again to make it work.

I found this happening only with this software. Any ideas about how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

This most likely a problem with the program itself. Try sending in your issue to the actual developer team. Also most likely you can say force stop on the application instead of deleting and reinstalling.

Comment: I didn't delete the app. Ever. It was uninstalled by mistery

Comment: Yeah to be honest I think it's probably program issue. Low possibility about if the device has some sort of issue with a software it deletes it automatically, the reason why I can say this is because I am testing an app I built myself and it sometimes fail on phone but never deletes it.

Comment: I'll surely have to check if this happens with other programs. The game on an A500 works even because the A500 never hangs to a forced reboot. I was thinking about some kind of file system issue, because AFAIK Android apps are plain apk files in a specific directory, and APKs are no more than plain old JARs

Comment: Yup, definitely check it out. apk can only be deleted by the user or a program which deletes it.